# How to Properly Get a File from resources Folder

Tags: java, resources, classloader

Many tutorials for reading a file from a resources folder use class loader. However, using that method I cannot get past problems with static warnings and the result is always a null pointer exception.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder contentBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        ClassLoader classLoader=Test.class.getClassLoader();
        File file=new File(classLoader.getSystemResource("test.html").getFile());
        try {
            BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String sCurrentLine="";
            while ((sCurrentLine=buffer.readLine())!=null) {
                contentBuilder.append(sCurrentLine);
            }
            buffer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        String content=contentBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println("content="+content);
    }
}
```

The warning from my IDE on the "File" line is:

> The static method getSystemResource(String) from the type ClassLoader should be accessed in a static way

I cannot figure out how to eliminate the warning and if I just ignore it and run the code I get a null pointer exception. Why am I getting this and how do I fix it? TIA.

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.html").getFile()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Maven but does that matter? Your suggestion got rid of the warning but I still get the null pointer exception. If it could not find the file, for whatever reason, wouldn't I get a file not found exception instead? Does this not imply something wrong with "ClassLoader.getSystemResource"?

Comment: Why is this a bad question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test.class.getClassLoader();` obtains a reference to the `ClassLoader` class from the `Class`' method `public ClassLoader getClassLoader()` - see `private final ClassLoader classLoader` below.

Since you are accessing the `ClassLoader` class from an object of that class, you're not accessing it in a static way.

From `Class.java`, *Java SE 1.7*:

```
@CallerSensitive
public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();
    if (cl == null)
        return null;
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
        ClassLoader.checkClassLoaderPermission(cl, Reflection.getCallerClass());
    }
    return cl;
}

// Package-private to allow ClassLoader access
ClassLoader getClassLoader0() { return classLoader; }

// Initialized in JVM not by private constructor
// This field is filtered from reflection access, i.e. getDeclaredField
// will throw NoSuchFieldException
private final ClassLoader classLoader;
```

In order to access the method in a static way, it has to be called from the class which declares it as static if you want to get rid of the warning:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.html").getFile()
```

To avoid the NPE the `test.html` file should be under your source folder.

---

To respond to your comment, using a method which returns other than a [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) solves your problem - see [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar).

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.html");
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((sCurrentLine = buffer.readLine())!=null)
                contentBuilder.append(sCurrentLine);
            buffer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("content=" + contentBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I asked in my comment to Shantu if the file path was wrong I'd get a file not found exception rather than null pointer. Assuming you are saying the path is wrong, my path is Test->src->resources->help.html. So would the file path then be 'resources/test.html"?

Comment: I tried the path 'resources/test.html" and then I got the file not found exception. This is very confusing as now I don't know where the null pointer exception is coming from. Interestingly if I follow the path in the traceback, the file is indeed there.

Comment: @Wt Riker I've added some more tips: hope it'll help

Comment: Thanks but no joy. I think the bottom line is that this problem has to do with the directory structure and finding the target file. I'm stumped. I tried "/test.html", "test.html", "resources/test.html", "src/resources/test.html" but same exception on them all. Including Hearen's suggestion.

Comment: @Wt Riker I tested the solution above and it works in Eclipse and in a jar with the file in `src` or in `resources`. Anyway... good luck! Double check your file name: *help.html* or *test.html*? ;-)

Comment: What was the file path you used when it was in src->resouces? Or do you have resources at the same directory level as src rather than under src?

Comment: at the same level like Eclipse does: resources should be a **source** folder

Comment: Ah ha!!!!!!!!!! The one path I did not try: "/resources/test.html". Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Obvious things are always a pain when debugging :D

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try to read them all at once:

```
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    String content;
    try {
        content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(loader.getResource("test.html").toURI())), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you are using **maven**, do please remember to set the **resources** based on your case (either as `Sources Root` or `Test Sources Root`).

By the way, your solution is alright using `Test.class.getClassLoader();`.